# creating absolute url for css in YII2 framework

Tags: php, css, yii2

I need to convert the following link into absolute url form. Please help me to change this link.

> css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to type:

```
/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css
```

If the "css" directory is within the root of your website, if it is not then you need to direct to that path, for instance if you have to go inside an "assets" folder to get to your "css" folder, the path would be:

```
/assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css
```

Hopefully this answers your question.